# Ajax for PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I wanted to load the content from separate files for a menu on a page (each menu option has separate content file .txt ). I want only the  for content area to change. I wrote a code declaring a xmlHttp variable. This variable is a browser variable hence will it be able to fetch data for me?

I am designing an android app in cordova.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui-content" data-role="main">
        <div id="A4FullspecsSideMenudiv">
            <ul data-icon="arrow-r" data-role="listview" id=
            "A4FullspecsSideMenu">
                <li><a class="ui-state-persist" href="#" id="A4Design" name=
                "A4Design" onclick="contentfetch()">Design</a></li>

                <li><a class="ui-state-persist" href="#">Technical
                Data</a></li>

                <li><a class="ui-state-persist" href="#">Efficiency</a></li>

                <li><a class="ui-state-persist" href="#">Equipments</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="AudiA4Content">
            <h3>Text about Design</h3><br>

            <p>Text about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about
            DesignTextText about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText
            about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText
            about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText
            about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about Design<br>
            <br>
            Text about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about
            DesignTextText about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText
            about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText
            about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText
            about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about Design<br>
            <br>
            Text about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about
            DesignTextText about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText
            about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText
            about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText
            about DesignText about DesignText about DesignText about Design<br>
            <br></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The text of this A4Content is to be changed. I did some reading and made text.html what 4  tags and separate text in each.

```
function contentfetch() {
    var txt = $("#A4div1").load("A4Specs.html");
    $("#A4Design").click(function() {
        $("AudiA4Content").val(txt);
    });
}
```

Execute this script on

```
 <li><a href="#" onclick="contentfetch()" id="A4Design" class="ui-state-persist">Design</a></li>
```

Comment: Then show us the code please sir :)

Comment: text of A4Content is to be changed on click of for example Technical Data

Comment: why you want load html file?

Comment: because it had text that i needed to show on click of the menu option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did It,

used the $("AudiA4Content").load("MyHtml.html #thedivwithInfo");